# Why I can't read the first line of the file?

Tags: python

When I read line by line from the file, the first line is skipped. Why does this happen and How can I solve this?

```
web="www.instagram.com/"
f= open("accounts.txt","r")
ft=open("add.txt", "w")
links=[]
for l in f:
    name=f.readlines()
    print(name)
    fullweb=web+name
    links.append(fullweb)
    ft.writeline(fullweb)
f.close()
ft.close()
print(links)
```

Comment: Can you share the raw content of the file `accounts.txt`?

Comment: @esqew they are instagram user ids written line by line.

Comment: Regardless, this should result in a `TypeError` becuase you can't add a string and a list

Comment: What is the point of `for l in f:`? That begins iteration over `f`, but then in the body of the "loop" you ignore `l` (which *is* the missing first line) and do `f.readlines()` instead. Tangentially, `l` is a poor choice of a variable name since it looks too much like the number `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You were starting iterating over the file `f` (as iterator)

```
for l in f:
```

getting the **1**st line and then, immediately read all its remaining contents with `f.readlines()`.
That makes no big sense (if not saying - no sense).

Comment: It doesn't make a small sense either.

Comment: @JohnColeman, indeed, just didn't want to upset the OP too much )

Answer (score 1):

You should either do for l in f or f.readlines, not both!

```
with open("accounts.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    ...
```

or

```
with open("accounts.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

Explanation:

With the iterator, you already iterate over the lines in the file. So it already "eats up" the first line, than you reach "readlines" readlines reads the other lines of the file. So doing both, is plainly not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think I should have used the iteration variable instead of calling the function to readline().Anyway this solved the problem.

```
for l in f:
 print(l)
 fullweb=web+l
 links.append(fullweb)
 ft.writelines(fullweb)
```

But I don't know the theory behind how the for loop reads the file line by line without any function.